# Not Allowing users Add same Named Child Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is my Firebase Database Structure]

I was Trying to add childs(Programmes) to the Above reference STUDENTS.

So the issue is when I retrieve the keys and add them to the ArrayList of Strings.

And check Whether it Matches the entered Text it gives ;
Like Example; in the photo, we have Three Programmes bps,cs,mm.

it gives me matches, not matches,not matches result
what I want is whether it matches or not like as above.

CODE

```
        // retreiving the edittext to String
        String prnamez = programmeName.getEditableText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

        // checking if the program already exists
        FirebaseAuth autha = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        DatabaseReference dnn = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Admin").child(autha.getUid()).child("INSTITUTE")
                .child("STUDENTS");

        // arraylist to add the keys of the programme
        ArrayList<String> pgName = new ArrayList<>();


        // value event listener
        dnn.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // going through all the keys and adding them to the arraaylist of pgName
                    for (DataSnapshot regis : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                        // retrieved the programme Name
                        pgName.add(regis.getKey().toString());


                    }

                    // going through the lenght of the array list
                    for (int i = 0; i < pgName.size(); i++) {

                       // if the entered programme matches already existing programme name
                        // then show this custom Toast

                        if (pgName.get(i).equals(prnamez)) {
                            // custom Toast
                            StyleableToast.makeText(Programme_students.this,
                                    "Matches", R.style.exampleToast).show();
                        } else {

                            StyleableToast.makeText(Programme_students.this,
                                    "not Matches", R.style.exampleToast).show();
                            
                            // WANT TO ADD NEW PROGRAMME IN THIS CASE 
                        }


                    }


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: If the Programme name Already Exists then the user will be prompted the Toast else he will be allowed to add the programme. when i trying to create the new programme by seeing if the Programme already Exists by .equals to functions, if i entered cs its giving me Toast not matches, matches, and not matches all i want is to go give me matches or not matches, if matches toast else create new programme.